# CMAKE - Build a list of functions

Tags: list, function, cmake

I try to do a list of functions. I don't know if it's possible because nobody never spoke about that before (in my research). I tried this :

```
function (enable_sdl)
    add_definitions("-DMINKO_PLUGIN_SDL")
    message("test")
endfunction ()

list (APPEND test enable_sdl)

list (GET test 0 foo)

${foo}()
```

It don't build because, apprently I can't use ${} when I'm not in the command.

Can anyone have an idea in order to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: This question didn't helped me because I want to know how to do an array of function not a dynamic named function.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the question about dynamic function name differs from one about function's array. (However, in some extent, array of functions is just a way to invoke the function with a dynamically constructed reference). But the answer is the same: **you cannot to do that**. You may "model" array of functions with dynamic function's name - `test_0`, `test_1`, so answers to the referenced question can be useful for you. Could you describe, **why do you need a function's array**? It is very possible that your problem can be resolved by other means.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will choose the naming method. Function's array are not mandatory in my case.